# Conditional INSERT in MariaDB (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables. The first contains the data about sensors (group, name, latest update, etc.). The second the readings for all sensors.

I now want to check if the latest update of a sensor is not too long ago, and if so,  insert a null value into the readings table for that sensor.

I tried some IF statements, but without luck. Should I go for INSERT and  "where IN()"?

Comment: Woud you please edit your question to provide sample data and expected output ? As it is, your question does not contain enough information to get an accurate answer.

Comment: And `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: i would take a look into a [View WITH CHECK OPTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-check-option.html) ... "The WITH CHECK OPTION clause can be given for an updatable view to **prevent** inserts to rows for which the WHERE clause in the select_statement is not true"... In MySQL it can also be used to simulate the missing CHECK constraint for the CREATE TABLE statement. Make sure to use [ALGORITHM=MERGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html) in the CREATE VIEW statement to get the best performance

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right path. It's effectively an INSERT with a WHERE clause
So what you need to do is create a record in the Readings table for Sensors that have an UPDATE past X days (10 in my example below)

Something like :

```
insert into readings
select 1 as id, id as sens_id, null as info
from sensors
where datediff(now(),latest_update) > 10;
```

In my example, I provide an ID but I assume that it's an autoincrement integer in your BD...

and then, update the UPDATE field...

```
update sensors set latest_update = now()
where datediff(now(),latest_update) > 10;
```

Go, try it by yourself...

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1EWRpH7nbxHEjwBDUgwLh/0

**UPDATE:**

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1EWRpH7nbxHEjwBDUgwLh/1

If latest_update is indexed, I suggest this instead :

```
where date_add(now(),INTERVAL -10 DAY) > latest_update;
```

to benefit from the indexing.

"When you wrap a function around an indexed column SQL Server must compute the value of the function for each row in the table.  When you just compare the indexed column to a scalar value or the result of a function then SQL Server can use that value to seek into the index."

Not sure exactly for MySQL since I didn't test it in this case but to be sure :)

https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/avoid-enclosing-indexed-columns-in-a-function-in-the-where-clause

Comment: MySQL/MariaDB has a better native way with a [updateable view and with check option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-check-option.html) .. "The WITH CHECK OPTION clause is used to **prevent** updates or inserts to views unless the WHERE clause in the SELECT statement is true."... In MySQL it can also be used to simulate the missing CHECK constraint for the CREATE TABLE statement.. Make sure to use [ALGORITHM=MERGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html) in the CREATE VIEW statement to get the best performance